# Flickr API - auto tags not showing up in lists returned by flickr.tags.getListPhoto

Tags: tags, flickr

Flickr's tag API doesn't seem to return all of the tags for a given photo.

Flickr began automatically tagging photos a month or two ago.  So now a given photo can be tagged with zero or more *user* tags added by users, and zero or more *machine* tags added by Flickr's algorithms.

Flickr's API offers the flickr.tags.getListPhoto method for retrieving tags.  But it only seems to return *user* tags. https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.tags.getListPhoto

The tags that are returned (the user tags) all include a machine_tag="0" pair, so I assume there's a way to get the machine tags, at least planned if not implemented.  Here's a JSON example of the output from getListPhoto:

```
{ "photo": { "id": "18791800953", 
    "tags": { 
      "tag": [
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-3318", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "downtown", "_content": "downtown", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-1306", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "skyscraper", "_content": "skyscraper", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-553", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "building", "_content": "building", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-16588", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "high-rise", "_content": "highrise", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-4603", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "Las Vegas", "_content": "lasvegas", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-6215", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "Nevada", "_content": "nevada", "machine_tag": 0 },
        { "id": "126228644-18791800953-291", "author": "126251698@N03", "authorname": "jorgemolina37", "raw": "urban", "_content": "urban", "machine_tag": 0 }
      ] } }, "stat": "ok" }
```

In addition to the above user tags, this image also has machine tags such as "blackandwhite", "outdoor", and "monochrome" that are not returned in the JSON: https://www.flickr.com/photos/miamiboy/18791800953/

I haven't seen anything in the documentation that discusses machine tags (or even mentions them), presumably because they're new.

Am I missing something?  Is there a parameter or another method I missed somewhere?  Or are the machine tags just not available (yet?)?

Answer (score 0):

The getPhotos service allows you to specify 'extras' to be returned. You can specify 'machine_tags' as one of the extras: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I tried adding `machine_tags` as an extra, and the returned JSON had a `machine_tags` field, but the field was empty for all of the images I tried, even for images that show machine tags when browsed on the web.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Machine tags are different that autotags. [Machine tags](https://www.flickr.com/groups/51035612836@N01/discuss/72157594497877875/) are added by people (or software) and are otherwise normal tags of the form `flora:tree=coniferous`, but have some special handling. [Autotags](https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157652019487118/) are added by Flickr using image recognition. But it seems the autotags [aren't actually available through the API](https://www.flickr.com/groups/51035612836@N01/discuss/72157650985879334/). Let me know if you find out otherwise! (Or you could scrape the page...)

Comment: The autotags functionality it's still not available on October 2018. Maybe one day...